# it:scalastyle not working for integration tests' folder

Tags: sbt, scalastyle

The scalastyle configuration in `build.sbt` is set as follows:

```
(scalastyleConfig in Test) := baseDirectory.value / "scalastyle-config.xml"
(scalastyleConfig in IntegrationTest) := baseDirectory.value / "scalastyle-config.xml"
```

Nevertheless, the `sbt "it:scalastyle"` does not check the source files in the `/src/it` directory. This command just ignores the `it` and checks the sources in the `/src/main` directory.

`sbt "test:scalastyle"` works fine.

Any idea on how I can fix this issue?

**Update:** After I remove the configurations in the `build.sbt`, I am still able to use `test:scalastyle` but not `it:scalastyle`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use `lazy val IntegrationTest= config("it") extend Test` to define `it`
,then you can use the following code  which just modified from the plugin's source code.

```
Project.inConfig(IntegrationTest)(rawScalastyleSettings())

(scalastyleConfig in IntegrationTest) := (scalastyleConfig in Test).value

(scalastyleConfigUrl in IntegrationTest) := None

(scalastyleConfigRefreshHours in IntegrationTest) := (scalastyleConfigRefreshHours in Test).value

(scalastyleTarget in IntegrationTest) := target.value / "scalastyle-it-result.xml"

(scalastyleFailOnError in IntegrationTest) := (scalastyleFailOnError in Test).value

(scalastyleSources in IntegrationTest) := Seq((scalaSource in IntegrationTest).value)
```

Relevant Github issue: Github issue: https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle-sbt-plugin/issues/64

Comment: compiler complained about `rawScalastyleSettings()`, but the solution in the github issue worked.